# Formatting first four words in first paragraph of each chapter for the entire document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I format my manuscripts in MS Word for publication. I want to format the first paragraph of each chapter.

The following requires me to go to each first paragraph and select the words I want to turn into 'small caps'

```vb
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "[a-z]{1,}"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 9.5
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
      Wrap:=wdFindStop
End With
Selection.Range.Case = wdUpperCase
With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
    .RightIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceMultiple
    .LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(1)
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
    .WidowControl = True
    .KeepWithNext = False
    .KeepTogether = False
    .PageBreakBefore = False
    .NoLineNumber = False
    .Hyphenation = True
    .FirstLineIndent = InchesToPoints(0)
    .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
    .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
    .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
    .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
    .LineUnitBefore = 0
    .LineUnitAfter = 0
    .MirrorIndents = False
    .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
    .CollapsedByDefault = False
End With
```

I'm looking for a version of this that would automatically select the first four words in the first paragraph of each chapter for the entire document.

The first paragraph has a distinct style from the Word 'Normal' style.

There is a page break and a chapter title that uses Heading 1.

Comment: Is there a Section Break (Next Page) immediately before the first paragraph of each chapter? Or is there a chapter title between a section break and the first paragraph? These kind of structural elements make it simpler to program if they are consistent.

Comment: Currently, there is a page break and a chapter title that uses Heading 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each chapter begins with a Heading 1 style title ... and assuming I understand correctly that the next paragraph (first paragraph in the chapter) you want the first four words to be small caps ... this should do it:

```
Sub HeadingOneRange()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, i As Long
    Dim rng As Word.Range, iRng As Range
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Style = doc.Styles("Heading 1").NameLocal
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            rng.Select
            Set iRng = rng.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range.Paragraphs(2).Range
            With iRng
                .Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
                .MoveEnd Word.WdUnits.wdWord, Count:=4
                For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
                    If .Characters(i).Case = wdLowerCase Then
                        .Characters(i).Font.Size = 9.5
                        .Characters(i).Case = wdUpperCase
                    End If
                Next
            End With
            rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Action Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Rich. This worked beautifully, but I should have clarified: I don't use the smallcaps attribute because certain file formats and e-readers don't support them, so the recommendation is to use all caps with a font size difference. The trick (that I tried) is to only select the lowercase and change their size and *then* change them to uppercase so that they appear to be smallcaps. Is there a way to include those steps in this script? Thank you!

Comment: @Gregory I edited the above to what I think you are asking concerning the lower case letters in the first 4 words of the paragraph.

Comment: @Gregory, I also agree with macropod about how the routine can be made better by creating a character style with the size and upper case set. A command like  .Characters(i).Style = doc.Styles("MyStyle").NameLocal would replace the two lines where I set the size and upper case.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rich!!! This is perfect! You've helped me a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to define paragraph and character Styles with the attributes you want to use, then apply those Styles to the content concerned. Brute-force formatting changes increase the likelihood of document corruption. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveDocument
  'Create a paragraph Style for content following Heading1
  If .Styles("Head1Next") Is Nothing Then .Styles.Add Name:="Head1Next", Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph
  With .Styles("Head1Next")
    With .ParagraphFormat
      .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
      .LeftIndent = 0
      .RightIndent = 0
      .SpaceAfter = 0
      .SpaceBefore = 0
      .WidowControl = True
      .KeepWithNext = False
      .KeepTogether = False
      .PageBreakBefore = False
    End With
    'With .Font
    '  .Name = "Arial"
    '  .Size = 12
    'End With
  End With
  'Create a charcter Style for Small Caps
  If .Styles("SmallCaps") Is Nothing Then .Styles.Add Name:="SmallCaps", Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter
  With .Styles("SmallCaps").Font
    .AllCaps = True
    .Size = 9.5
  End With
End With
On Error GoTo 0
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Style = wdStyleHeading1
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    Set Rng = .Characters.Last
    With Rng
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Style = "Head1Next"
      Do While .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) < 4
        .MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        With .Words.Last
          .Case = wdUpperCase
          .Start = .Start + 1
          .Style = "SmallCaps"
        End With
      Loop
    End With
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You say «the first paragraph has a distinct style from the Word 'Normal' style», but you don't say what that Style's name is. Accordingly, my code both creates and refers to that Style as 'Head1Next'.

Note the 'Do While .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) < 4' loop. This is necessary to ensure 4 actual words are included; otherwise, punctuation in the range is liable to throw the word count off.

If you add the 'Head1Next' and 'SmallCaps' Styles to the document or its template, you can omit everything between 'On Error Resume Next' and 'On Error GoTo 0' relating to that Style. With the 'Head1Next', you can also add any other font characteristics you'd prefer the paragraph as a whole to employ, as indicated by the commented-out font references.

Comment: Thank you so much, macropod--I tried this, and it gave me the error Compile error: Method or data member not found. Do I need to add those styles to make it work? I made sure I copied everything exactly as you posted it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I also realized I should have clarified: I don't use the smallcaps attribute because certain file formats and e-readers don't support them, so the recommendation is to use all caps with a font size difference. The trick (that I tried) is to only select the lowercase and change their size and then change them to uppercase so that they appear to be smallcaps. Is there a way to include those steps in this script? Thank you!

Comment: «it gave me the error Compile error» Fixed. I've also revised the code in light of your further clarification and comments.

Comment: I know this isn't the right place to say thank you, but--THANK YOU. You've helped me so much!