# Counting words and ignoring new lines in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to count all the words in a document, while ignoring new lines as words.
For example, running the following code on the next example:

```
    For Each sentence In x.StoryRanges
    For Each w In sentence.Words
            i = i + 1
     Next
    Next
    MsgBox i
```

Example:

---

This is a test

Still Test

---

Would echo "7" instead of 6 words (this,is,a,test,still,test) because of the empty line

Any hack to counter it?
Thanks

Comment: There's an add-on app that will do this accurately for you. Search AuthorTec Statistics. I am the author. If you are incorporating your custom code into something else, then @TimothyRylatt has posted the correct answer for you, and please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about looping through `Sentences` and `Words` as you cannot get accurate results that way. Instead use the [`ComputeStatistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.computestatistics)  method of the range you want to count the words in. For example

```
ActiveDocument.Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop through x number of words? - For example, find out if the word "Test" shows in the first 100 words of a document.
Or how many times a word repeats in 100 word radius?

Comment: @Biezor - See the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909289/macro-for-formatting-word-document-by-style-paragraph/65913245#65913245